# Image send via TCP

Tags: python, opencv, tcp, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send data of the captured image via TCP Socket using python (raspberry PI ). 
TCP Server (QT) runs on other machine and tries to read the image and display in QLabel.

I have never programmed in python and totally don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have spend lots of time ( days ) to cover ongoing errors and finally got to the point that I can actually run it. But data what I am receiving is piece of junk.

Below program displays video in sep window on raspberry PI and should send the individual captured image via socket.

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import cv2
import time
from socket import socket
import sys
import numpy

cv.NamedWindow("camera",cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

sock = socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.0.2', 5001))
sock.send('Pi - Hallo')

while True:
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", frame)

    mat = cv.GetMat(frame)
    buf = [1,90]

    image = cv.CreateImage (cv.GetSize (frame), 8, 3)
    nuImage = numpy.asarray(frame[:,:])
    imgencode = cv2.imencode('.png', nuImage, buf)
    data = numpy.array(imgencode)
    stringData = data.tostring()
    sock.send('Pi - Sending image data');
    sock.send( stringData );

    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break

sock.send('Pi - closing connection')
sock.close()
```

Comment: well, if you are receiving "piece of junk" there is simply an encoding & decoding problem. try to debug and see.

Answer (score 13):

The data  you received is not junk. It is the send data. But it is send in bytes. So, at the receiving end, you need to convert the bytes in to string before processing the data. Read [this](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.in/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for better understanding of sending and receiving data in socket programming and read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) for methods used in current version of opencv.

Also your dont need to use cv to do this task. Current version of opencv provides methods to do so just by `import cv2`.

The following is a working code though it's communication is simplified.

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import cv2
import numpy

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 5001

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = capture.read()

encode_param=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),90]
result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
data = numpy.array(imgencode)
stringData = data.tostring()

sock.send( str(len(stringData)).ljust(16));
sock.send( stringData );
sock.close()

decimg=cv2.imdecode(data,1)
cv2.imshow('CLIENT',decimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import cv2
import numpy

def recvall(sock, count):
    buf = b''
    while count:
        newbuf = sock.recv(count)
        if not newbuf: return None
        buf += newbuf
        count -= len(newbuf)
    return buf

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 5001

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(True)
conn, addr = s.accept()

length = recvall(conn,16)
stringData = recvall(conn, int(length))
data = numpy.fromstring(stringData, dtype='uint8')
s.close()

decimg=cv2.imdecode(data,1)
cv2.imshow('SERVER',decimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I think you have an error here - your line decimg = cv2.imdecode(data,1) should be replaced with:

decimg =data.reshape((480,640,3))

Comment: Can I ask you if it's an efficient way to send image via socket? and will socket good for large number of image? (sorry, I'm new to socket)

Comment: Its been 4 yr since this posted and im not sure that if some new efficient method is developed.

Comment: in general in order to sen VIDEO stream using raw sockets you must use UDP protocol. BUT here is a common problem that you may come across [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921388/python-receiving-image-from-socket-stream?rq=1). In general sending big stream over TCP is "bad" practice